# Is it possible to create a unique index on a list of subdocuments?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to create an index on the LastName of the members in a band. The structure looks like this:

[image]

I've tried these two approaches:

```
collection.EnsureIndex("Members.LastName");
```

and

```
collection.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder().Ascending("Members.LastName"), IndexOptions.SetUnique(true));
```

But I can still add members with the same last name. Is it even possible to create an index on a subdocument list with MongoDB? If so, how?

**Edit**

When I check in MongoVue, the index is there, so it *is* being created:

[image]

And here's the index for the id field:

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't a band be allowed to have more than one member with the same last name?  What if it contained a brother or sister of one of the members?

Comment: This is just my example. My code for my real job isn't about bands and members. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code sample in the question is actually correct. The problem is that you created the index the first time without being unique. Just drop the index and run your second code sample again:

```
collection.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder().Ascending("Members.LastName"), IndexOptions.SetUnique(true));
```

I havent used the C# driver of MongoDB, but I tell you how its done in the shell. Lets say we have a sample document,

```
{"_id": ObjectId(...)
 "name": "John Doe"
 "address": {
    "street": "Main"
    "zipcode": 53511
    "state": "WI"
    }
}
```

Then to create the index on the address.zipcode(as is the case with you) you do,

```
 db.people.ensureIndex( { "address.zipcode": 1 } )
```

To ensure that its unique, you do

```
 db.people.ensureIndex( { "address.zipcode": 1 },{ unique: true } )
```

I think you are missing out the unique part. For more info heres a link to the docs [1](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/)
and [2](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/)

If you have duplicate docs in the collection and dont mind losing them, you could also even use the [dropDups](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-creation/) Command.

Comment: My question shows the unique part in my second code snippet.

Comment: is the index actually created then?I mean did you check in the collection?

Comment: Yes. I just added the screenshot to my question.

Comment: I just added the screenshot for the index for id.

Comment: Ok..looks like you ran the ensureindex without the unique, the first time and then with unique the second time..

Comment: That was it! So my code was correct (well, the second snippet, anyway). The problem was that I first created the index as not being unique. I just deleted the index and ran the second code snippet and it's working now. If you want to adjust your answer to cover this, I'll accept it. Thanks!